# ffmpeg using exec() output must be realtime

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, exec

Hi I am suing windows and linux OS and I am using php for uploading videos, using ffmpeg I can convert videos to other file type. in commandline I can convert and thru php code, but I have problem in displaying the output executed data in my php, it cannot be done in `echo` this is my code.:

```
$webm = 'ffmpeg -i c:\xampp\htdocs\vidcon\video.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -aq 5 -ac 2 -qmax 25 -threads 2 c:\xampp\htdocs\vidcon\new\myvideo.webm';
    echo exec ($webm);
```

but when I run it, it doesn't have any display.. what I want to display is like this... something like a progress in converting the video displaying in php...

`ffmpeg version N-68810-g75cc57f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  1 2015 22:02:35 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavformat    56. 16.102 / 56. 16.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'c:\xampp\htdocs\vidcon\video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2014-03-04 20:25:21
  Duration: 00:02:33.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2661 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709)
, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2499 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 t
bc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-04 20:25:21
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-04 20:25:21
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
[libvpx @ 0292c560] v1.3.0
Output #0, webm, to 'c:\xampp\htdocs\vidcon\new\myvideo2.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf56.16.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9],
 q=-1-25, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-04 20:25:21
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.19.100 libvpx
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default
)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-04 20:25:21
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.19.100 libvorbis
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   12 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       5kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=  97.1kbits/s
frame=   22 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=       5kB time=00:00:00.73 bitrate=  52.9kbits/s
frame=   31 fps= 19 q=0.0 size=     153kB time=00:00:01.03 bitrate=1213.8kbits/s
frame=   41 fps= 19 q=0.0 size=     153kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate= 917.5kbits/s`

does anyone had an idea about my case? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

You need to pass an array as the second argument.

From the docs:

*If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array.*

```
$webm = 'ffmpeg -i c:\xampp\htdocs\vidcon\video.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -aq 5 -ac 2 -qmax 25 -threads 2 c:\xampp\htdocs\vidcon\new\myvideo.webm';
$array = array();
echo exec ($webm, $array);
```

This should do it.

This is a way to show real time output of your shell commands:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");

// tell php to flush after every output
// including lines of output produced by shell commands
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    // Turn off PHP output compression
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
    // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
    ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    // Clear, and turn off output buffering
    while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
        // Get the curent level
        $level = ob_get_level();
        // End the buffering
        ob_end_clean();
        // If the current level has not changed, abort
        if (ob_get_level() == $level) break;
    }
    // Disable apache output buffering/compression
    if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
        apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
        apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
    }

$command = 'ffmpeg -i etc';
system($command);
```